# How to feed my own data to BERT by getting the right placeholder from the tensorflow graph

Tags: tensorflow, named-entity-recognition, bert-language-model

I am trying to fine tune BERT for NER. I have downloaded a checkpoint from here (https://storage.googleapis.com/bert_models/2018_10_18/uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12.zip)

I have loaded the session and graph using this code:

```
model = "./cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/bert_model"
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model + ".ckpt.meta")
new_saver.restore(sess, model + '.ckpt')
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

Now, I'm trying to get the input placeholders from this graph to create my own feed_dict and define my own loss function. I examine the graph using the following code:

```
op = sess.graph.get_operations()
[m.values() for m in op]
```

and the only placeholders that I find are listed below:

```
[(<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(1, 128) dtype=int32>,),
 (<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=(1, 128) dtype=int32>,),
 (<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_2:0' shape=(1, 128) dtype=int32>,),
```

These placeholders look incorrect to me for the following reasons:

1. I expected them to be of size (None,512) as this BERT model accepts sequence length of maximum 512 and the batch_size should not be predetermined. Based on this size I see here, this BERT model accepts 1 sequence at a time with max size of 128. Why is this?
2. I believe we have to feed a set of sequences, their lengths and corresponding labels. Of these three placeholders, which is which?

Comment: This is much simpler if you just use [tf hub](https://tfhub.dev/s?q=bert).  Load the embeddings using `hub.Module` and set `trainable=True`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. I was hoping I could do it the old fashion way.

Answer (score 0):

The typical use of BERT model for downstream tasks needs to rebuild the graph and load the weight/bias values from the pretrained model, as done in the example scripts like `run_classifier.py`.

It's possible to run the model in the old fashion way by defining the placeholders by yourself and feed them to the model (as the inputs of BertModel constructor) when building the graph.

Note that `is_training` is defined as a bool variable, but not a tensor, in BertModel, which makes some small code changes necessary if you also want to feed a placeholder into it.